# Find a number which satisfies the constraints

Tags: algorithm, search

I have two numbers `P` and `K`. I have an array `A` of `N` integers.I want to find the least number `A[i]` which just satisfies the property `abs(A[i]-P) <= K` where `0 <= i < N`.
It is given that `A` is sorted.

Initially, I thought of `O(N)` approach. But I think that it can be optimised to `O(logN)` by using binary search. But I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: This is ongoing programming competition: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/epiccode/challenges/dance-in-pairs

Comment: O sorry I was unaware of this fact.I will clarify my doubt after the contest gets over.Actualy my doubt is with reference to this question "https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/infinitum-jul14/challenges/sherlock-and-probability"

Comment: there is an editorial for that challenge. You can just read it, and I highly doubt that someone here write an answer more detailed than it is written in the editorial.

Comment: There's no explanation for this question in the editorial."https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/infinitum-jul14/challenges/sherlock-and-probability/editorial".

Comment: then I would just write a private message to the guy, who should have written an editorial asking for it.

Comment: [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) will solve it for you in O(log N) in one line of code, my friend (if you're using c++)

Comment: @FalconUA:i tried your approach but that was not working for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 for(i=0; i<=n; i++)pre[i]=0;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
            pre[i]=pre[i-1];
            if(s[i-1]=='1')pre[i]++;
    }
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
            if(s[i-1]=='0')continue;
            ans += pre[min(n,i+k)]-pre[max(0ll,i-k-1)];
    }
    LL gc=gcd(ans,n*n);
    cout << ans/gc << "/" << (n*n)/gc << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following logic:

- Find minimum number index that `>= abs(P-K)` using binary-search, if not found go on,
- Find minimum number index that `<= (P+K)` using binary-search, if not found then there is no such a number.

It's `O(log(n))` I think.